# How do I uninstall the Gestures Python GUI app from 19.04

Tags: python, uninstall, 19.04

I've installed 19.04 on my Dell Venue 11 Pro and, while it works with the touchscreen, it doesn't have a lot of the gestures that make it even more functional. I found this app called Gestures, which is a GUI for libinput-gestures. I installed the prereqs, and it worked, but the GUI part wiped out the default configuration for libinput-gestures and couldn't find the config file. I modified the config file for the app, but it still didn't work.

So, now I'd like to just go back to the default settings for libinput-gestures, and skip the GUI bit, but I don't know how to process an uninstall, nor can I find anything about how to do so. I ran the following in the terminal:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures
cd gestures
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Any suggestions would be wonderful :)

Comment: Go to the source directory. See if it has `install_log` file or something similar. It should list all of the files it put into the system. Oh, if the application wipe out your config for `libinput-gestures`, i'm not sure how you'll get the file back.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thanks for being the only person to respond in two days :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the code a bit (https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/blob/master/gestures/configfile.py)

it looks like it does seem to create a backup

```
self.filePath = path + "/.config/libinput-gestures.conf"
self.backupPath = path + "/.config/libinput-gestures.conf.bak"
```

try

```
mv ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf.bak  ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try These steps. First go to below directory to manually remove icon/launcher or desktop entry

    cd /usr/share/applications
then paste these lines to remove it 

    sudo rm -r org.cunidev.gestures.desktop
```

after that follow these steps

```
cd /usr/share/metainfo

sudo rm  -r org.cunidev.gestures.appdata.xml
```

it will remove the meta info
and you'll not found the gesture in your launcher